# Can I combine Create and List class based generic views using mixins?

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views, django-1.3, django-class-based-views

I'm looking for the easiest way to combine List and Create functionally with generic class views.
I want to have a page that has an item list and a form to add a new item on the bottom.

**I thought that mixin architecture would allow to combine necessary classes** but I had no luck yet.

This almost works:

```
class ResourceListView(ListView, BaseCreateView):
    context_object_name = 'resources'
    model = Resource
    form_class = ResourceForm
```

But `form` isn't accessible inside template and the thing crashes on invalid output (when form is valid, it's fine).
This may have to do with multiple inheritance but I'm not really into Python yet so it gets too confusing.

Is there a simple way to combine some of the [mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/) into a view-and-create View, or do I have to roll out my own?

Comment: I think this is the same issue that I have read (and answered) in [this post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338181/django-mixing-listview-and-createview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Note: I no longer advocate this solution, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9339798/458193) is a much cleaner one.

By trial and error (and looking at Django source), I wrote this:

```
class ListCreateView(ListView, BaseCreateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()

        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        kwargs.update({'object_list': self.object_list, 'form': form})

        context = super(ListCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Works fine both for creating and listing (although it may issue a few extra database calls, not sure).

Comment: Worked very fine for me! For update, I will use an extra page, but for list/create, it is so good!