# Django best practices - how would you create a page with a form and a list of items the Django-way?

Tags: django, forms, listview, mixins

I'm starting with django (and stackoverflow!)

I've been trying to create a webpage with a form and a list of items. ( [Django - Mixing ListView and CreateView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338181/django-mixing-listview-and-createview/9345881)). I came up with a solution but I'm not convinced by my code!

I'm using Django mixin `BaseCreateView` and `BaseListView` to generate the form and list context data. But because it's views, they call directly `render_to_response()`.

So I overloaded the `get()` method to manually call both parents methods and extract the context data. Then I called `render_to_response()` myself.

```
class FormAndListView(BaseCreateView, BaseListView, TemplateResponseMixin):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formView = BaseCreateView.get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) # formView contains a response_class
        listView = BaseListView.get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)   # listView contains a response_class as well...
        formData = formView.context_data['form']                      # extract the form from the response_class 
        listData = listView.context_data['object_list']               # extract the object list from the response_class

        return render_to_response('textfrompdf/index.html', {'form' : formData, 'all_PDF' : listData},
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

On one hand I'm not re-writing what is already in the mixin to manage forms and lists of items... On the other hand, django is calculating the whole `render_to_response()` 3 times!

**What would be the clean Django-way to write this page?**

Comment: If you are just starting out with Django, use plain old functions for views. Figure out how it works there before taking on the new class-based views.

Answer (score 1):

```
class FormAndListView(BaseCreateView, BaseListView, TemplateResponseMixin):

    def render_to_response(context, **responsekwargs)
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        context.update( BaseCreateView.get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) ) # formView contains a response_class
        context.update( BaseListView.get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) )  # listView contains a response_class as well...

        return TemplateResponseMixin.render_to_response('textfrompdf/index.html', context,
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: This returns 'FormAndListView' object is not iterable exception.