# Django framework: ListView with CreateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am new in django programming, and I have simple question.

I have model

```
class Dhcp(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('gateway',)
        verbose_name = _(u'DHCP Configuration')
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'DHCP Configurations')

    gateway = models.IPAddressField(_(u'Gateway'), null=True)
    dns_primary = models.IPAddressField(_(u'DNS Primary'), null=True)
    dns_second = models.IPAddressField(_(u'DNS Second'), blank=True)
    leases_time = models.IntegerField()
    nat = models.IPAddressField(_(u'NAT'), blank=True)
    max_time = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.gateway
```

and my question is :

And I want to list all my dhcp objects which are in database, and add more object. But I want do that on same template.

For example: If I have 3 objects in database, show that and show form for add more obj. When I add one more object from form, I want to show the added object.

Thanks!

Dusan Ristic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/), more specifically the [ListView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.4/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) and [CreateView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.4/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/). This question comes up quite often, so you should find the answer on here somewhere. [Check this post out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12883683/1428653).

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
class DHCPView(forms.CreateView):
    model = Dhcp
    template_name = "list_and_create_dhcp.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs["object_list"] = Dhcp.objects.all()
        return super(DHCPView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Ok tnx. It was useful for me!!